# Thread limits for Azure Load Testing

Tags: azure, load-testing, azure-load-testing

Azure Load Testing (Preview) has a limit of 250 threads per Engine Instance. Each test can only run up to 45 Engines, so the theoretical maximum number of concurrent sessions that can be run is 11,250.

I need to simulate 120k concurrent users. Is there a suitable workaround to do this with ALT?

Comment: TL;DR: **not currently**, and for the reasons you explicitly cite in your question (11,250 hard limit per resource) - it's not clear what you would expect as a complete answer in light of this fact. It should be *hypothetically* possible to spin up multiple instances (11 of them to be exact) of ALT resources configured exactly the same, but you lose the nice things that come with doing this within a single resource (mainly centralized reporting), but you also run the risk of Azure viewing this as abuse or circumvention of their limitations and the penalties they may impose as a result.

Comment: Looking for a workaround if there is one. I can run two ALTs in the same subscription with 45 engines each, but when I create the third I hit another limit, 100 engines per subscription. ALT seems to have a long way to go before it's production-ready.

Comment: I would agree with your sentiment, but I don't think it's reasonable to expect anything more from a feature clearly marked `PREVIEW`. If you need this you should look elsewhere until this product graduates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to contact [Azure Support](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2202692&clcid=0x409&culture=en-us&country=us) for the details.

In the mean time be informed that you don't need 3rd-party providers to run a JMeter test without any limits, given you have a subscription you can

- [kick off several virtual machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/virtual-machines/)
- [install JMeter on these machines](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)
- run your test in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

which is pretty much what Azure Load Testing is doing under the hood